# Qual expressão regular seria mais apropriada para validar uma expressão de Cronjob?

Tags: regex

Estou querendo aprender um pouco mais sobre expressões regulares. Pensei num bom exercício que será validando se uma expressão cronjob está correta ou não.

[image: Imagem do cronjob]

Sendo assim, as possíveis combinações abaixo deveriam retornar verdadeiro de acordo com a suposta expressão regular.

```
 * * * * *

1-15 */5 0,30 * 5

0,30 * * * 1-5
```

Lembrando que todos os números acima representam uma expressão válida de Cronjob.

Outro detalhe é que expressão deve conter 5 "membros" separados por espaço. Esses membros, como exemplificado acima, devem ser de acordo com o representado na imagem.

A expressão pode ser avaliada como:

```
<minuto><espaço><hora><espaço><dia_do_mês><espaço><mês><espaço><dia_semana>
```

Para quem não entende como o cronjob funciona aqui vai um pequeno exemeplo:

## Executa de hora em hora

```
0 * * * * comando
```

## Executa de uma hora em hora, de 1 às 5

```
0 1-5 * * * comando
```

De acordo com a imagem acima, como eu poderia criar uma validação para uma expressão cronjob?

Preciso apenas de validar o conteúdo referente a definição do tempo que será executado, não preciso validar o comando que vem depois da expressão.

**Nota**: Preciso apenas da lógica para aprender regex, então qualquer linguagem é válida para a resposta.

Comment: Começa aqui http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/

Comment: A virgula, asterisco e a  barra significam  o que?

Comment: A vírgula e a barra são caracteres literais, o asterisco é um quantificador guloso.@rray

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, isso se trata mais de um algoritmo do que uma REGEX, por exemplo, se `1-15` quer disser de `1 a 15` minutos, e `0,30` 0 ou 30min você tem sentenças diferentes `(0?[1-9])|(1[0-5])`, `0|30`. Especifique melhor os parâmetros :D

Comment: Coloca 1 linha de exemplo completa pra facilitar....

Comment: Complementando a dica do @MagicHat, se você quer aprender expressões regulares o livro do aurelio é um bom investimento.

Answer (score 2):

Patrão,***simplex***, é tipo assim ???

Bom não sei se compreendi direito o que está querendo, mas...

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Valida cron:</legend>
<h1>Formato</h1>
<div>&lt;minuto&gt;&lt;espaço&gt;&lt;hora&gt;&lt;espaço&gt;&lt;dia_do_mês&gt;&lt;espaço&gt;&lt;mês&gt;&lt;espaço&gt;&lt;dia_semana&gt;&lt;espaço&gt;&lt;comandos&gt;</div>
<h3>Exemplo</h3>
<p>* * * * * /sbin/ping -c 1 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null</p> 
<input id="jota" type="text"/><button type="button" onclick="valida()">Valida</button>
<p id="isvalid"></p> 
</fieldset>


<script>
 function valida(){
 var filter_cron = /^\s*($|#|\w+\s*=|(\*(?:\/\d+)?|(?:[0-4]?\d)(?:-(?:[0-4]?\d)(?:\/\d+)?)?(?:,(?:[0-4]?\d)(?:-(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:\/\d+)?)?)*)\s+(\*(?:\/\d+)?|(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:-(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:\/\d+)?)?(?:,(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:-(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:\/\d+)?)?)*)\s+(\*(?:\/\d+)?|(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:\/\d+)?)?(?:,(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:\/\d+)?)?)*)\s+(\*(?:\/\d+)?|(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:-(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:\/\d+)?)?(?:,(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:-(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:\/\d+)?)?)*)\s+(\*(?:\/\d+)?|(?:[0-6])(?:-(?:[0-6])(?:\/\d+)?)?(?:,(?:[0-6])(?:-(?:[0-6])(?:\/\d+)?)?)*)\s+|s+)([^\s]+)\s+(\s*.*)$/;
 if(!filter_cron.test(document.getElementById("jota").value)){
  document.getElementById("isvalid").innerHTML = "Cron inválido";
  document.getElementById("jota").onfocus = function keydown_e(){
 document.getElementById("isvalid").innerHTML = "Tente novamente você consegue ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯";
    }
 }
 if(filter_cron.test(document.getElementById("jota").value)){
  document.getElementById("isvalid").innerHTML = "Válido";}
  
 }
</script>
```

[Referência e Guia <<<<<<< Aqui se aprende rapidão](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/)

[StackOverflow tem tudo que queremos, ou quase tudo !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235504/validating-crontab-entries-w-php)

Comment: Na verdade, precisa validar o "*", o "0-5" ou "0-9", ou "*/9""

Comment: São apenas essa variáveis ou  possuem mais?ex: quando diz "0-5"significa de 0 até 5 ou o "0". o "-" e o "5", especifique bem o que quer validar...